# Widgeting with wordpress page editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is there some way to create a widget or placeholder for some content that should be only shown if i use some special tag in page editor?
For example: I have a special menu, that i want to define with page editor, but it should be shown outside of page content.

[image]

So if i write in editor something like this, it should put this in my optional menu:

```
[menu]
   <ul>
      <li><a>Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Menu Item 1</a></li>
   </ul>
[/menu]
<div>
    Some content for my page
</div>
```

Is there some pugins or tricks or some filters etc. in wordpress for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just like a menu then go to function.php file and register a menu with you specific name like this.

```
register_nav_menu( 'your-menu', __( 'Your Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
```

and then show that menu conditionally on inside your div.

```
<?php if($var==1) : ?>
<div>
wp_nav_menu(array());
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and if you have some different content then register custom fields for pages and show output those fields with conditional statement. 
hope it make sense to you.
Cheers!

Comment: But i want to define the content of this menu with page editor and not with template editor. And each page can have own optional menu. It can be also a widget instead of menu. Can i set this $var with an editor or how can i decide which page is shown?

Comment: Again the same solution register fields for pages. those fields shall show up in all pages u have created. then for conditional things use WP-option-tree plugin and create options for page where you want to show and where u don't want to.
look at this reference link for creating custom fields for your pages.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: It was not exactly what i was looking for, but it solve my problem with menu. Thanks. The other way was to use widgets in template and assign a custom menu to a widget. But i cann't define css classes for my menu in a widget.